# Android: on screen orientation change fragment.getActivity is null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'll try to explain my problem:

all my fragments are using setRetainInstance(true)
In my activity onCreate I'm doing this:

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragment = onCreatePane();
        fragment.setArguments(intentToFragmentArguments(getIntent()));

        FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.add(R.id.root_container, fragment, getFragmentTag());
        trans.commit();
    } else {
        FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if ( fragment == null ) {

            fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag());
        }

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = onCreatePane();
            fragment.setArguments(intentToFragmentArguments(getIntent()));
        }           

        trans.add(R.id.root_container, fragment, getFragmentTag());
        trans.commit();

    }
```

So when I create the activity and savedInstance is null I create the Fragment, I set it's arguments, I begin the transaction and add my fragment to the transaction with it's own tag (to get it back later).

The user interact with the activity and change the orientation. The activity is destroyed and recreated (as normal activity lifelycle). So now it enter the else, the fragment is null and I do a `fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag());` that returns the correct Fragment holded by the fragmentManager.

The problem is that this fragment hold a reference to the old Activity that has been destoyed so if I do a fragment.getActivity it returns null. How can I update the fragment reference to the acitivy to the new re-created Activity?

**UPDATE**: To be more precise I'm on the SearchActivity that call the onNewIntent when it get a new Search. So the actual interaction is this-> user do a search -> search is displayed correctly -> user change orientation, result is displayed correctly (if user interact with results they are fine) -> user do a new search from the search button and this call the SearchActivity's onNewIntent that dispatch the new intent to the fragment that has the search logic. Here it crashes because the reference to the activity is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove null check from else part  `if ( fragment == null ) {  fragment = getSupportFragmentManager(` ...... let update fragment with new one created on orientation change  ......

Comment: I can assure you that when the screen orientation is changed it enters always in that if so the fragment references is updated with fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag()); also it return a NOT NULL fragment. The problem is that the Fragment references to the activity is still null (it wont update it with the new re-created one)

Comment: it's ok .. I know that when orietnation will change you 'll get fragment variable as null.......... I just asked that as I think it may be initialized before line "if (savedInstanceState == null) {"

Comment: I think that I solved my issue with getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag()); what I need to do is to do it in another point of the code :) now it works fine but I need more testing :)

Answer (score 1):

When and where are you calling `getActivity()`? The activity reference does get updated automatically, but not immediately. You should be safe to access it after `onActivityCreated()` was called.

Comment: To be more precise the getActivity is used in the onNewIntent of the acitivty that call onNewIntent on the fragment.

Comment: And when exactly is onNewIntent one called? Orientation changes don't cause this, so I guess you're calling it manually? At any rate, it seems you're doing it too early. Make your fragment remember what you needed to tell it and only let it act on it when onActivityCreated is called

Comment: To be more precise I'm on the SearchActivity that call the onNewIntent when it get a new Search. So the actual interaction is this-> user do a search -> search is displayed correctly -> user change orientation, result is displayed correctly (if user interact with results they are fine) -> user do a new search from the search button and this call the SearchActivity's onNewIntent that dispatch the new intent to the fragment that has the search logic. Here it crashes because the reference to the activity is null

Answer (score 0):

If setRetainInstance(true) -- yes, it's the solution (to find fragment by tag, because instantiate it again -- is the wrong way -- there could be background routines in progress). Otherwise, if you have setRetainInstance(false) the problem can be back.
I had the similar one. I my case -- because I used Loader (in background). Solution was simple: to destroy fragment's loaders in onDestroy() method of the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In your baseAcvivity you can override onSaveInstanceStat to resolve this problem :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //solution of fragment.getActivity() is null
    outState.remove("android:support:fragments");
}
```